# Congrats to DucatiKiller for reaching 7000 points!

Tags: discussion, congratulations

Great job @DucatiKiller! You have reached out to the community and they have responded :D We really appreciate you being here and putting effort into your answers and assisting others when needed! Looking forward to you doubling this and reaching 14k ... at this rate it won't be long :D

Comment: Thank Paul.  Really like it here.  It's been a blast!  Good folks in here!  Thanks for all your help as well as @Zaid for answering my endless litany of questions that I could have answered myself had I searched   :-)  Appreciate it.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - You know that's why I hang out here, is just to help you, right??? J/K! It's great having you here! I'm glad we have a good MC guy around to answer those pesky questions :D

Comment: @DucatiKiller Well done, thanks for all your contributions so far! The big 10k is coming up for you shortly!

Comment: Good stuff @DucatiKiller. You definitely are a reason Ive stayed around. :)

Comment: Thanks @racefever  Mighty kind of ya!